# Como mostrar continuamente valores en una casilla de Entry usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, sensor

tengo un problema al momento de refrescar los datos que se muestran en el entry ya que solo lo puedo mostrar una vez, y lo que quiero que haga el código es que cada cierto tiempo me este actualizando el valor mostrado, estoy usando tres sensores de temperatura y los estoy adquiriendo usando una Raspberry, El código que estoy usando es el siguiente, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

```
import bme280
import smbus2
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *



port = 1
address = 0x76 # Adafruit BME280 address. Other BME280s may be different
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)

bme280.load_calibration_params(bus,address)
   
def imou ():

    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    humidity  = bme280_data.humidity
   
    return humidity
    

def imou1 ():

    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    pressure  = bme280_data.pressure
    return pressure
    

def imou2 ():

    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
   
    ambient_temperature = bme280_data.temperature
  
    return ambient_temperature 
    
win = Tk()

while variable < 1000
    
imou()
e = Entry(win,width=10)
e.pack()
e.insert(0,imou())

imou1()
e1 = Entry(win,width=10)
e1.pack()
e1.insert(0,imou1())

imou2()
e2 = Entry(win,width=10)
e2.pack()
e2.insert(0,imou2())

win.after(2,imou,imou1,imou2)

mainloop()
```

Gracias por su ayuda, espero y tengan un excelente día.

Comment: Cual es el proposito de ese `while variable < 1000`? Tal como está, tu código debería dar un error de sintaxis debido a que a dicho le faltan dos puntos y no hay ningún código dentro de dicho while. Si me respondes, podré hacer las pruebas con seguridad y responderte.

Comment: Dejé una respuesta en esta pregunta: [¿como leer un valor del sensor de temperatura en un entry programado en tkinter de manera continua?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465124/como-leer-un-valor-del-sensor-de-temperatura-en-un-entry-programado-en-tkinter) Te sirve?