# ¿como leer un valor del sensor de temperatura en un entry programado en tkinter de manera continua?

Tags: python, tkinter

soy nuevo en python, en este momento estoy tratando de leer valores de temperatura de un sensor, pero no puedo mostrarlos de forma continua en mi interfaz insertando los valores en un entry. ¿ Como puedo hacer que se refresquen estos valores cada determinado tiempo? Es decir lo que trato de hacer es leer mi valor del sensor en un entry que programe en tkinter

```
import bme280
import smbus2
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

port = 1
address = 0x76
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)

bme280.load_calibration_params(bus,address)

def imou ():
    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    humidity  = bme280_data.humidity
    return humidity
    

def imou1 ():
    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    pressure  = bme280_data.pressure
    return pressure
    

def imou2 ():
    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    ambient_temperature = bme280_data.temperature
    return ambient_temperature 
    
win = Tk()
while variable < 1000

imou()
e = Entry(win,width=10)
e.pack()
e.insert(0,imou())

imou1()
e1 = Entry(win,width=10)
e1.pack()
e1.insert(0,imou1())

imou2()
e2 = Entry(win,width=10)
e2.pack()
e2.insert(0,imou2())

win.after(2,imou,imou1,imou2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hay una pregunta justo abajo de la tuya cuyo creador tiene la misma duda y código que tu. Es decir, que ya existía esta duda de antes. Por favor, evita preguntar lo que ya se ha preguntado. Lo digo para que no aparesca muchas veces la misma pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: Los podré ayudar si me explican el proposito de ese while...

Comment: Estaba haciendo pruebas con el ciclo while para refrescar los datos pero no sé pudo, pero se me pasó quitarlo de mi código. Saludos

Comment: Dale! Gracias c: Ya escribo una respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO ES c:

Para lograr lo que buscas vamos a usar un par de cosas:

#### Variable de control: StringVar

Cuando tenemos un entry el cual le cambiaremos constantemente su valor, conviene más usar una variable de control, la cual de valor tendrá lo que está escrito en el entry.
Las variables de control (en nuestro caso StringVar) tienen un método llamado set, que nos permite cambiar el contenido del entry a otro.
Por ejemplo `entry.set("hola mundo")` hará que el entry tenga escrito "hola mundo".

Información adicional: https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html

#### ventana.after(delay, func)

After es un método común a todos los widgets. El primer argumento (`delay`) le dice a Tkinter cuanto tiempo tiene que pasar antes de ejecutar la función. `func` es la función a ejecutar.

Mas información: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/la-funcion-after-en-tkinter/

#### Código de ejemplo

El siguiente es un código de ejemplo que creé en base a tu código. Como no tengo raspberry ni los sensores que usar, tuve que hacer un sustituto para las pruebas. Las tres funciones generan un numero decimal aleatorio entre 0 y 10. Además, los entrys se refrescan cada segundo. A pesar de esto, el código debería de servir para que puedas aprender como aplicarlo a tu caso.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def imou():
    humidity = random.uniform(0, 10)

    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv.set(humidity)

    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou)
    
def imou1():
    pressure = random.uniform(0, 10)

    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv1.set(pressure)

    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou1)
    
def imou2():
    ambient_temperature = random.uniform(0, 10)
    
    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv2.set(ambient_temperature)

    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou2)
    
win = Tk()

# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv = StringVar()
# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou()

# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv1 = StringVar()
# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e1 = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv1)
e1.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou1()

# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv2 = StringVar()
# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e2 = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv2)
e2.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou2()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola, muy buenas noches. Pude resolver el problema gracias a tu ayuda y obtener en mi interfaz los valores de mis sensores. Ahora estoy tratando de resolver está duda. He tratado de meter los valores de otro sensor a un "entry" el cual me permite saber la velocidad en km/h, pero aún no logro generar un entry para mis funciones. Espero me puedas ayudar. Dejo el link de mi pregunta. saludos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465217/c%c3%b3mo-insertar-el-valor-saliente-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-un-entry-con-tkinter